# Boolean values in MySQL, Perl DBI, and JSON

Tags: mysql, perl, json, dbi

Consider a simple mysql table with columns `id` (an integer) and `flag` (a boolean).
A user interface written in JavaScript communicates to a CGI backend via JSON, both for receiving data from the table and for updating it.

Now, when sending the data `{id: 5, flag: true}` to the server, I of course use `from_json` to get a perl hash(ref). Then

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE my_table SET flag = ? WHERE id = ?);
$sth->execute($data->{flag}, $data->{id});
```

always results in a false value being inserted. I believe this is because of the magic behaviour of JSON::true and JSON::false, which stringify to 'true' and 'false', respectively (but would numify to 1 and 0). Apparently, the execute statement provides string context, and not numeric context, so the mysql server receives a string containing no numbers, which then causes the value 0 to be inserted. For now, I fix this by putting `? 1 : 0` after `$data->{flag}`.

In the other direction, the opposite wrong thing happens: According to DBI's doc, "Most data is returned to the Perl script as strings.", so when I hit the result of a SELECT query with `to_json`, the values are received by the UI as JavaScript strings "0" and "1", which are both true in JavaScript. So for now I do a `$_->{flag} += 0 foreach (@result)` before applying `to_json`.

Question: At which point(s) in the chain should I insert these 'hacks'? In the JavaScript end, I could for example make sure to send the values 1 and 0 instead for true and false, and reread the flags as numbers. Is there something I can tell DBI to make it return numeric columns as (scalars which JSON would consider as) numbers?

Answer (score 4):

Been there and done that. Initially I added 0 to the numbers in the JSON we decoded in Perl but it was tiresome and time consuming because I had to loop through a large structure adding 0 to all the numbers. Then I helped Tim Bunce add [sql_type_cast](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.616/DBI.pm#sql_type_cast) to DBI so that a few minor changes to DBD::Oracle could use it to return numbers instead of strings (they are still Perl scalars but with some internal tinkering - see below).

The problem I had was I was using JSON::XS and it looks at scalars in encode_json to see if the pv or iv is set to decide whether to produce "0" or 0 in the encoded JSON. DBI's sql_type_cast and the new DBIstcf_DISCARD_STRING attribute means I now bind numeric columns as $s->bind_col(1, \my $col, {TYPE => SQL_INTEGER, DiscardString => 1}) and sql_type_cast will remove the scalar's pv if it looks like a number. The problem is that the DBD needs to change to use sql_type_cast. DBD::Oracle is changed and I just changed DBD::ODBC in 1.31 to do it as well.

Maybe you could change DBD::mysql in the same way or persuade someone else to (I don't use mysql).

See [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/dbi-dev@perl.org/msg05504.html) for a long discussion on the implementation of DiscardString etc.

You can find a test in DBD::ODBC called sql_type_cast.t which tests DiscardString works without using JSON::whatever.

UPDATED: [another link to discussion on dbi-dev](http://www.mail-archive.com/dbi-dev@perl.org/thrd5.html)